# Errata for Hungerford's Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request

Currently reading the category theory section of Hungerford's *Algebra* (the GTM), and I am noticing an *egregious* amount of typos. However, I have been at a loss to find an errata for this text, despite it seemingly being rather well known. Could anyone suggest an errata?

Comment: Why don't you post all the errata your have found. Then we can check it. I will post the errata I have found. Then this post can eventually be a list of errata of the book.

Answer (score 2):

Exercise 7.7. in chapter 8 states that $V(I_1 \cdots I_k) = V(I_1) \cap \cdots \cap V(I_k)$ holds for affine varieties, but this should be modified to $\cap_{\alpha}V(I_\alpha)=V(\sum_{\alpha} I_\alpha)=V(\cup_{\alpha} I_\alpha)$. A counter-example is obtained if we consider the ideals $(x), (y) \subset k[x,y]$.

Answer (score 2):

p.75, Exercise II.1.11.(b).
$\mathbb{Z}$ should be $\mathbb{N}^+$.

p.187, line 10.
$s_i\in D$ should be $s_j\in D$.

p.204, line -6.
$j=0, 1, 2, ..., n$ should be $j=1, 2, ..., n$.

p.223, line -10.
"$C$ contains an element of order $n_2$" should be "$C$ contains an element of order $p^{n_2}$".

p.241, line 4.
$K(u_{\sigma_{(1)}}, ..., u_{\sigma_{(n)}})$ should be $K(u_{\sigma(1)}, ..., u_{\sigma(n)})$

p.389, line 6.
$\overline{R}$ should be $R$.

p.333, line -11.
"$u=u_1x$" should be "$u=u_1 x_1$".

p.396, line 5.
$(r_{11}-s)b_1+r_{12}, b_2+\cdots +r_{1n}b_n=0$ should be $(r_{11}-s)b_1+r_{12}b_2+\cdots +r_{1n}b_n=0$

p.396, line 7.
$r_{n1}b_1+r_{n2}, b_2+\cdots +(r_{nn}-s)b_n=0$ should be $r_{n1}b_1+r_{n2}b_2+\cdots +(r_{nn}-s)b_n=0$

p.475, line 1 and 2.
Some prime symbol $'$ do not be placed in a proper position.